# ACF: display custom filed of CPT into the loop

Tags: loop, advanced-custom-fields

I have a CPT called Project (Projects in plural) and I am displaying it in the loop into a column.

I would like to display a custom field I have into this CPT (called "type") underneath the title in the loop.

How can I display custom filed values in the loop?

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 offset--1 col-md-12">
<div class="result-card">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php if (empty(get_the_post_thumbnail_url())){echo get_template_asset_path("/img/placeholder-image.png");}else{echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url();} ?>" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block lazyload" alt="placeholder image" /></a>
    <div class="container-result-card">
        <div>
            <div class=" ">
                <blocs-php-snippet> the_field( 'type' ); </blocs-php-snippet>
                
            </div>
            <h3 class="mg-md result-title h3-style">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-price">
                <div>
                </div>
                <p class="mg-md">
                    Price
                </p>
            </div>
        <div class="card-location">
                <div>
                </div>
                <p class="mg-md">
                    Location
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant code so we can know what you already have/tried to do?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Just updated my post

Comment: Add the loop code as well please. BY the way, the section with `the_field( 'type' );` is missing `<?php` `?>`, no idea what `<blocs-php-snippet>` is but ok.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast it was the missing `<?php ?>`

Thanks